# My javascript is only working with ID. Not working with Class

Tags: javascript

I have a autoclick script which is working with javascript. But it is working only with ID. I need to add it multiple section of page. I tried `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementByClassName`. But it was failed. Please convert it from ID to class name.

**Not Working with Class**

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="hello-btn" target="blank">Google</a>

<script>
var helloBtn = document.getElementByClassName("hello-btn");

helloBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Btn clicked");
});

var interval = window.setInterval(() => {
  helloBtn.click();
}, 4000);
</script>
```

**Working with Class**

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="hello-btn" target="blank">Google</a>

<script>
var helloBtn = document.getElementById("hello-btn");

helloBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Btn clicked");
});

var interval = window.setInterval(() => {
  helloBtn.click();
}, 4000);
</script>
```

Comment: Classes can be used by multiple tags, so your getElement*s*ByClassName returns a list. You need to set up the listener for each of them.

Comment: You use function `getElementByClassName` , this function doesn't exist. You can't get element by class name, you can only get elementS by class name. And function `.getElementsByClassName` return node list array. So you have to go through each element of the array and bind an eventlistener to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is called `getElementsByClassName`. It can return multiple results and if you want to attach a handler to all of the returned results, you need to iterate over them:

```html
<a href="#"class="hello-btn">Google</a>
<a href="#"class="hello-btn">Microsoft</a>
<a href="#"class="hello-btn">Facebook</a>
<a href="#"class="hello-btn">Azure</a>
<a href="#"class="hello-btn">AWS</a>
```

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("hello-btn");

Array.from(buttons).forEach((helloBtn) => {
    helloBtn.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
      console.log(`clicked button ${evt.target.innerHTML}`);
    });
});
```

Please note, that `getElementsByClassName` does not return an array, but an array-like object: The HTMLCollection https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection?retiredLocale=de

**Update:**
To get the desired auto click functionality working, you could go like this:

```js
var autoclickInterval = setInterval(()=> {
  Array.from(buttons).forEach((helloBtn) => {
      helloBtn.click()
  });
}, 5000)

//clearInterval(autoclickInterval)
```

Comment: Did you checked? I checked.. It is not working..

Comment: Yeah, definitely works https://jsfiddle.net/rnf6xp2g/

Comment: I am trying to make auto clicker script for multiple links like `<a href="https://www.google.com" class="hello-btn" target="blank">Google</a>`
`<a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="hello-btn" target="blank">Faceboook</a>`

Comment: The script works with anchor tags, too. https://jsfiddle.net/emb9cfhx/

Comment: Autoclick is not working.. I need auto click in every specific  interval like
`var interval = window.setInterval(() => {
  helloBtn.click();
}, 4000);`

Comment: Autoclick was never part of your question. You wanted to make getElementsByClassNames working. However I've updated my answer

Comment: Could you update all codes together ?

Comment: I am trying to autoclick on my DataTables. Autoclick on every 5 seconds (**th** class **sorting_asc**) https://codepen.io/themecode/pen/dyevdEy
 Here this code is not working .. Can you make it as always working ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no method like getElementByClassName. But getElementsByClassName (note the "s"). simply get the first element from array.

```
var helloBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("hello-btn")[0];
```

should work as intended.

Comment: He needs to class name, because he wants to add it multiple times on a page. Getting the first one, will not be enough. He needs all of them.

Comment: It is working only 1 link. I cant add multiple times

Comment: This is working. But not working with multiple like `<a href="https://www.google.com" class="hello-btn" target="blank">Google</a>`
`<a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="hello-btn" target="blank">Facebook</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with `const helloBtn = document.querySelector(".hello-btn");` or `querySelectorAll`?

```js
// Use const instead var
const helloBtn = document.querySelector(".hello-btn");

helloBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Btn clicked");
});

const interval = window.setInterval(() => {
  helloBtn.click();
}, 4000);
```

Then you can use `<a href="https://www.google.com" class="hello-btn" target="blank">Google</a>` with **class** selector.

Comment: This is working. But not working with multiple like `<a href="https://www.google.com" class="hello-btn" target="blank">Google</a>`
`<a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="hello-btn" target="blank">Facebook</a>`

Comment: That is true, the solution is to iterate over all the classes. If you use `const helloBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".hello-btn");` you don't need to create an Array from buttons. Just a small improvement.

Answer (score -1):

As the class name can be used by multiple tags. `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an Array.

**If you want to allow click to all buttons having the same class name.**
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/pLtjo5hn/

```
  var helloBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('hello-btn');
  
  for(var i = 0; i < helloBtn.length; i++ ){
    var btn = helloBtn[i];
    btn.addEventListener('click', function handleClick(event) {
      console.log('btn clicked', event.target.innerText, event);
    });
```

If you want to allow click to only 1st element/button having the same class name.
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0vnos7xr/

```
    var helloBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('hello-btn')[0];

    helloBtn.addEventListener('click', function handleClick(event) {
      console.log('btn clicked', event.target.innerText, event);
    });
```

*Note: If there is just 1 button to bind a click event, it is always better to use ID instead of Class Name.*

Comment: I am trying to make multiple autoclick with same class. Intervel also needed.. I dont see any effect in your Jsfiddle

Answer (score -3):

Try JQuery .bind() method, I used at several places

https://api.jquery.com/bind/